# electron+figwheel on Mac causes websocket connection error

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, figwheel

**Background**

I am trying to integrate [figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel) with [electron](http://electron.atom.io/)(atom-shell). I use

`lein new figwheel hello-world -- --reagent`

to generate `figwheel` part, and copied the electron part from [electron quick start](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.29.0/tutorial/quick-start/). The resulting project is [here](https://github.com/lotabout/cljs-douban).

**Question**

Run the project by:

1. Open a terminal and start figwheel `lein figwheel`
2. Open another terminal, start Electron by `electron .`.

However it fails on Mac. The electron part shows the following log:

`[5848:0720/220633:INFO:CONSOLE(62)] "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3449/figwheel-ws/dev' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response", source: file:///Users/foo/repos/cljs-douban/resources/public/js/compiled/out/figwheel/client/socket.js (62)
[5848:0720/220635:INFO:CONSOLE(82)] "Figwheel: trying to open cljs reload socket", source: file:///Users/foo/repos/cljs-douban/resources/public/js/compiled/out/figwheel/client/utils.js (82)`

However, the same project works on Linux. Googled and no correct result, Please kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googled for 'MAC websocket connection error', I got a similar problem [here](http://andrewbolster.info/2014/07/ipython-websocket-failure-on-chrome/).

And it is the proxy I set screwed 'localhost', which causes connection error. Disable the proxy fixed the issue. Sorry for any inconvenience.